# Order Python Dict by Property of Object in Value?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a python dict that looks like

```
people {"mykey1": myCustomObject, "mykey2": myCustomObject }
```

Within myCustomObject, I have an integer ID field. So that looks like

```
class myCustomObject:
    def __init__(self, myID, firstName, lastName):
        self.ID = myID
        self.FirstName = firstName
        self.LastName = lastName
```

Would it be possible to order this dictionary by the ID property within the custom object???

Comment: `dict` instances can *never* be ordered.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Except when they can be, by using an OrderedDict, which would be an instance of dict (check it!: ``>>> import collections; d = collections.OrderedDict(); isinstance(d, dict)``
``True``

Comment: @AaronHall: It's really just an accident of implementation that `OrderedDict` is a subclass of `dict`, so you probably shouldn't rely on that; if you want to check whether it's a dict-like object, use `isinstance(d, MutableMapping)` instead. But obviously you're right that you shouldn't assume it's _not_ a `dict` subclass, especially given that it happens to be one in fact, and documented as such. :)

Comment: @abarnert I know, I'm just being "smart". :) I just implemented a non-dict-inheriting MutableMapping in response to another question (which I coincidentally asked myself here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21361106/how-would-i-implement-a-dict-with-abstract-base-classes-in-python/21368848#21368848)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `dict` inherently has an arbitrary order.

If you just want to *access* it in a specific order one time, you can just sort it. If you don't know how to sort things using anything other than the default ordering, read the [Sorting HOW TO](http://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html). But basically:

```
for k, v in sorted(d.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[1].ID):
    print('{}: {}'.format(k, v))
```

If you actually want to *store* them in that order, you need some time that maintains order. Of course a `list` will work, but an [`OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) works like a `dict`, except that it maintains the order of insertion, which is more convenient for most use cases. So, if you create a new `OrderedDict` and then insert everything into it in sorted order, that would probably solve your problem:

```
d1 = { your original dict }
d2 = collections.OrderedDict()
for key in sorted(d1, key=lambda k: d1[k].ID):
    d2[key] = d1[key]
```

You can simplify this down to one line if you understand comprehensions:

```
d2 = OrderedDict(sorted(d1.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[1].ID))
```

Variations on similar examples are shown in the docs under [`OrderedDict` Examples and Recipes](http://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#ordereddict-examples-and-recipes).

If you instead want the dictionary to *maintain* sorted order, you will need some kind of sorted dict class. The stdlib doesn't come with such a class, but there are many options available on ActiveState and PyPI. Some are implemented as an `OrderedDict` that re-sorts itself every time you update them (or, sometimes, the first time you access them after an update, which allows a long chain of updates to avoid a long chain of sorts). Others use `bisect` or a search tree (e.g., a binary red-black tree or a 10-ary B-tree) to insert elements in the right place.

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you. The lambda expression definitely got me what I need.