# Why MutableMapping is not instance of dict?

Tags: python, dictionary, isinstance

I would like to create a dictionary-like object as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21361106/how-would-i-implement-a-dict-with-abstract-base-classes-in-python). Here is my example:

```
import collections


class DictLike(collections.MutableMapping):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.store = dict()
        self.update(dict(*args, **kwargs))

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.store[key]

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self.store[key] = value

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        del self.store[key]

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.store)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.store)


print(isinstance(dict(), collections.MutableMapping))
# >> True
print(isinstance(DictLike(), dict))
# >> False
```

For some reason, `isinstance` of the instance of my class `DictLike` is `False`. Why is this so? I expected that inheriting and implementing `MutableMapping` would be pretty much the same as normal dictionary.

I believe it is possible to override `__instancecheck__` method as described [here](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-instance-and-subclass-checks), but I don't know if it is a good idea and would be pythonic way?

Comment: It's the other way around: `dict` is a subclass of `MutableMapping`.

Comment: Not all mutable mappings are dicts. It wouldn't make sense to have `MutableMapping` inherit from `dict`, let alone be an instance of it.

Comment: `dict` is **not** in the `__mro__` of **MutableMapping**.