# use str.format() witch class in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, mapping, typeerror

I have a class with `__getitem__()` function which is subscribable like a dictionary. However, when I try to pass it to a `str.format()` i get a `TypeError`. How can I use a class in python with the `format()` function?

```
>>> class C(object):
      id=int()
      name=str()

      def __init__(self, id, name):
        self.id=id
        self.name=name

      def __getitem__(self, key):
        return getattr(self, key)

>>> d=dict(id=1, name='xyz')
>>> c=C(id=1, name='xyz')
>>>
>>> #Subscription works for both objects
>>> print(d['id'])
1
>>> print(c['id'])
1
>>>
>>> s='{id} {name}'
>>> #format() only works on dict()
>>> print(s.format(**d))
1 xyz
>>> print(s.format(**c))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#13>", line 1, in <module>
    print(s.format(**c))
TypeError: format() argument after ** must be a mapping, not C
```

Comment: It seems that your problem is not with `format()` but with `**`.

Comment: but wenn I remove it and go for `print(s.format(c))` it raises a KeyError

Comment: `c.__dict__` would get you inner dictionary. But I'd recommend adding some property to return it, rather than returning it directly. You can also make `C` inherit from `dict`, rather than `object`.

Comment: yes using `print(s.format(**c.__dict__))` does the trick. thx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How would I implement a dict with Abstract Base Classes in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21361106/how-would-i-implement-a-dict-with-abstract-base-classes-in-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As some of the comments mention you could inherit from `dict`, the reason it doesn't work is that:

> If the syntax **expression appears in the function call, the expression must evaluate to a mapping, the contents of which are treated as additional keyword arguments. In the case of a keyword appearing in both expression and as an explicit keyword argument, a TypeError exception is raised.

For it to work you need to implement the Mapping ABC. Something along the lines of this:

```
from collections.abc import Mapping


class C(Mapping):

    id=int()
    name=str()

    def __init__(self, id, name):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name

    def __iter__(self):
        for x in self.__dict__.keys():
            yield x

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.__dict__)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.__dict__[key]
```

This way you should just be able to use `s = '{id}{name}'.format(**c)`
 rather than `s = '{id}{name}'.format(**c.__dict__)`

You can also use `MutableMapping` from `collections.abc` module if you want to be able to change your class variables like in a dictionary. MutableMapping would also require the implementation of `__setitem__` and `__delitem__`